# Limited permissions for users logged in with facebook and twitter

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I would like to know if there's a way to allow people to log in into my Drupal site with limited permissions with their Facebook or Twitter account.

I have created a website which allows **authenticated users** to upload images. I have added a voting option which can be used by the authenticated users. I want to allow the people logged in with facebook or twitter to be only able to vote and not upload images.

I am using [Social Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/sociallogin) to allows users to login users with their facebook and twitter. Is there a way to set this limitation?

Comment: You mean that if user can directly login then they are able to upload images & vote. But if they are login through Fb or Twitr then they are able to vote only.

Comment: yes thats exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to automatically assign them specific roles, then limit permissions based on those roles.

[A few ideas about how to work with rules and auto-assigning roles](https://www.drupal.org/node/1872384).